# Confusion about interior gravitational potential/force

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, potential, planets

So I've followed and understood the proof that inside a *thin* hollow shell the gravitational potential is constant and hence the force is zero, but when applying it to a problem (namely "how does the force depend on the distance for an object dropped through the Earth in a narrow tunnel") I'm slightly confused:

The solution stated that only the sphere of mass "below" the falling object exerts a gravitational force. Is this because we have broken up the whole planet into 2 parts:

**Above the momentary position** (that is, all the mass that is farther away from the center of the earth then the object)

**Below the momentary position** ( The sphere with radius = position from the center)

so the "above" can be thought of as a bunch of thin hollow shells and hence it doesn't exert force, and the below part as regular ball of mass ?

Comment: Also check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you have understood is correct
Earth is a solid sphere.
You can break a solid sphere into infinite hollow spheres
So if you view all the hollow spheres above the momentary position individually, we can conclude force is 0 due to them (as object is inside the hollow sphere)
So we just take the mass of the sphere below the position